# How to get sum of all number from a Text by using xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

**Data for example**

```
<Value>YQ: LH YQ surcharge: 10.00 EUR; GB: United Kingdom Air Passenger Duty APD: 15.46 EUR; RA: Germany Passenger Service Charge International Departure: 26.59 EUR; DE: Germany Airport Security Charge: 9.50 EUR; OY: Germany Air Transport Tax: 7.38 EUR; UB: United Kingdom Passenger Service Charge Departures: 20.70 EUR</Value>
```

**Expected Result**
89.63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tokenize the input to individual charges, extract the numerical amount from each token and sum them up. In XSLT 1.0, this requires a recursive template:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Value">
    <total>
        <xsl:call-template name="total">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="concat(., '; ')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </total>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="total">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, ';')">
            <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before($string, '; ')" />
            <xsl:variable name="amount" select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($token, ': '), ': '), ' EUR')" />
            <xsl:call-template name="total">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '; ')" />
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + $amount" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: your code will not work if at last of the text we get other then EUR due to this line of code <xsl:variable name="amount" select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($token, ': '), ': '), ' EUR')" />

Comment: Then change it to a space. I am not clairvoyant and have no way of telling what in your input is fixed and what is just an example.

Comment: one more problem is here Actually i have to check if CommandList/GetBookingDetails/SupplierConfirmationCancelDataItemList/SupplierconfirmationCancelDataItem/Name ='Refund Amount Breakdown' then need to get the value from CommandList/GetBookingDetails/SupplierConfirmationCancelDataItemList/SupplierconfirmationCancelDataItem/Value and then we will tokenize it.

Comment: @SadikSiddiqui None of this is in your question. If necessary, post a new one.

Comment: Please help me for other problem on this next ticket, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61596075/numbers-sum-from-a-text-using-xslt-1-0 Thanks for previous Help.